# Enable Ports on Ubuntu Server - NGINX Reverse Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

My private IP is e.g. 175.34.55.2

```
ubuntu@ip-175-34-55-2:~$ sudo nmap -sT -p- 175.34.55.2
Not shown: 65531 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3128/tcp open  squid-http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

I have working reverse proxy on port 8080. How do I open port 8181, 8282, or 3000 on Ubuntu 18.4 so that I can use it with reverse proxy in Nginx?

My Nginx default file:

```
location /api1 {
    proxy_pass http://175.34.55.2.7:8080;
    ...
}
location /api2 {
    proxy_pass http://175.34.55.2.7:8181;
    ...
}
location /api3 {
    proxy_pass http://175.34.55.2.7:8282;
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need to add into the server section listen 12345

Comment: by the way location tells that apu1 can be found at a ip and port, you may also add a service or config part to nginx that it is listening to

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure, what you really want to achieve.
Normally, in general case, I do not think it is a good idea to make your webserver to listen on set of extraordinary ports.

Taking security to the game, we use [Mandatory Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) and services like [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) or [AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) to protect our servers to do not listen on such weird ports. It limits attack vector. 
Said that, I think you can achieve the same with [virtual host functionality](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/).

Answering the question, you just need to add another set of servers for nginx.

```
server {
    listen      175.34.55.2.7:8282;
    ...
}
```